# Character keeps moving for seconds when I let go of the movement key in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, linux, ubuntu, wine, lutris

I play *Skyrim* (GOG) on Ubuntu (using Wine and Lutris), and this bug is an ongoing debate that seems to be related to the game itself. I have looked over Steam discussions, and most of the links shared there are obsolete, and yes, there is the <kbd>C</kbd> button that will toggle sprint and then there is the "WASD" keypad that will do the movement. It doesn't matter what I type in between these four buttons; the player keeps moving as long as I press one of these buttons.

I am clueless about this, and I have no idea how I should fix it. I tried:

1. Plugging and unplugging my USB keyboard
2. Cleaning the insides of the keyboard

I am very much a noob with Ubuntu, so I don't know if changing my keyboard drivers will do any good. Help me out with this issue.

Comment: Please provide more information regarding the environment, including the exact OS build, hardware models, and version of the software (i.e. Gog, Lutris, TES Skyrim...).